# Unwrapping hyperlink from anchor tag using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to remove/unwrap hyperlinks from below element if the value is `-`

```
 $('span.name', this).after(`<span class="service-tier table-item-tier"><a class='service-link' href="https://link?search=${appName}" target="_blank" onclick="event.stopPropagation()">${selectedApp?.tier || '-'}</a></span>`);
```

I'm able to solve this using

```
$('.service-link').each(function () {
  var tag = $(this).html();
  if (tag == '-')
  {
    $(this).contents().unwrap();
  }   
});
```

Is there any other efficient way to solve the problem, I feel I'm unnecessarily looping through instead of applying required logic in above code.

Comment: Rather than removing the `<a>` elements that contain only `-` characters, why not test to see if the `selectedApp?.tier` exists (is true/truthy), and if not then don't create/insert the `<a>` element?

Comment: right, why didn't i think of it. Thanks @DavidThomas